# USB C ports not working in HP probook 450 g4 and Ubuntu 22.04 latest version

Tags: drivers, usb, hp, motherboard

The blue USBs on the right side doesn't work. I can charge my phone with them but cannot transfer data. Seems like it needs to install drivers. Similar issue has been fixed here in Windows: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-Notebooks/USB-Ports-stopped-working/td-p/6695869

Do you know how to fix this problem? Is there anyway to try install drivers? I tried the additional drivers GUI but there was only NVIDIA ones.

I already updated the bios

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice which allows older/newer kernel/kernel.modules to be used (aka *drivers*) but we don't yet know your *software stack* details; ie. what OS/product/release are you using?

Comment: @guiverc thanks, it's 22.04 latest version

Comment: Please add those details to your question, and please note *latest* is the Ubuntu 23.04 or the 2023-April release, with 22.04 being 3 releases ago ! (ie. Ubuntu 22.04 is the 2022-April release) so is it the *latest* or 22.04?  Please be clear.